# footer not stick to bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

i can't find the reason why the "footer" don't stick to the end of the page,and the body is not really 100% height.

I have the code in this link:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/107452929/flow/CWSMainTitle.htm

Comment: Do you want to put it at the end of the entire page, or at the bottom of the browser window ?

Comment: I want to put it at the end of the entire page.

Comment: Your footer has an `position: absolute;` ... dont do that .. make it `relative`. It will look then for its placement looking at the previous `<div>` element. It should fix it.

Comment: try .footer {position:absolute;margin-top:100%;}

Answer (score 2):

Add `position:fixed`

```
footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 30px;
}
```

---

If you want footer to stick to the bottom of the page then you need to add a div to wrap the entire code and give `position:relative` to wrapper div and retain your footer css as it is.

In this case footer has parent div to apply the absolute position but in your current code you don't have parent div to place the absolute position.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
your full html code here
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
position:relative;
height:auto;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BWaGx/2/)**

---

If you are not particular about `position:absolute` then you can just change that to `position:relative` and place the footer html tag to the end of the page. In this case you need not to add the wrapper div.

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/BWaGx/3/)

Comment: but if I use fixed instead of absolute there is going to be a problem once the table will have more items ,from what I know the right use of footer is with absolute position and not fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put your footer at the end of the entire page, then you have nothing to do, no absolute, no fixed : just a block after all the others.

Comment: from your answer I understand that I want the footer to be put on the bottom of the browser window,what should I do for that? tnx

Comment: Then position:fixed ! (with a margin on the bottom of your main content not to be hidden by the footer)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 
`min-height:100%` to the body.
And give `display:inline-block` to the wrapper of your content

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.footer {position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;}
```