# My footer is stuck at the bottom of the viewport

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website for a client. You can see it here: //removed link after closed answer.

But I have same troubles with my footer.

It's stuck at the bottom of the borwsers wievport, not the buttom of my page. If you try to zoom the browser in and out, you will see the problem.

I've tried placing my footer outside of my main-wrapper, but with the same result.

My footer css:

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1297px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index:2;
    height: 100px;
    left:50%;          
    margin-left:-648.5px;
    bottom:0px; 
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have added the fixed position on the website now. But I still have the same issue.

With position fixed, then the footer will always be visible to the bottom of the screen. I need it to be at the bottom of the page. So it will never overlap my `#sub-container`

**EDIT 2**

I have moved my footer outside my main-wrapper and my footer now looks like this:

```
#footer {
    background-color: #fff;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;  
    bottom:0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 1297px;
    z-index:2;          
    margin-left:-648.5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: [position:fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/nLk9c/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real ANSWER in authors word

> Thanks, I fixed it by putting my footer in the main-wrapper. Giving
>   the main-wrapper a height:auto; instead of 100% and then said
>   position:relative; for the footer

you can use absolute

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/arjun_chaudhary/h9mHc/27/)

> OR

You have position:absolute set on your  div, which will only ever use its CSS height value for the amount of space it takes up, regardless of its actual content. Removing that absolute position should solve your problems. There's (almost) always a way around absolute positioning. In your example, it seems completely unnecessary

Why not using: `{ position: fixed; bottom: 0 }`

Comment: I have added the fixed position now. But I still have the same issue. With position fixed, then the footer will always be visible to the bottom of the screen. I need it to be at the bottom of the page.

Comment: fixed is just an option u can use absolute also thats why i have included OR so see the demo

Comment: I have seen you demo, but I cannot see why it's different from what I did in the first place. I tried adding your code to the site, with no better result..

Comment: yaar your footer started moving down with page 5 min ago now when i refreshed it stopped what u have changed 5 min ago

Comment: I have edited my question where you can see the changes that I have done.

Comment: .footer {position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;}

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137117/footer-not-stick-to-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by putting my footer in the main-wrapper. Giving the main-wrapper a height:auto; instead of 100% and then said position:relative; for the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
position:fixed;
```

instead of

```
position:absolute;
```

And place `bottom:0px;` right after `position:fixed;`.
Hope it helps.

Plus experiment with body height:

```
body{height:1000px;/* or more, or less*/}
```

Change its value until your footer wouldn't make other body invisible.

Comment: This will have the same result unfortunately.

Comment: I have tried your solution, where I put position:fixed; and bottom:0px; right after. But I'm not looking for a position fixed solution. Since it would still overlap my content since the footer will always be set a the bottom of the browsers viewport. (And the bottom of the page) but it will still overlap.

Comment: @Adnaves But I edited. `body{height:1000px;/* or more, or less*/}`